# Sublimetext 3 indention guides not showing for every indent level

Tags: sublimetext3, indentation

I'm having an odd issue in sublime text 3. I have the indention guide lines turned on, but for some reason the guides are not showing for every indention level.

[image: missing guides]

I have my indention level set to four spaces. I double checked the number of spaces for the tags (b/c sometimes if you're missing a space sublime doesn't recognize it as a proper indention) and the number of spaces is fine:

[image: showing spaces]

I've been reading through the docs and looking in the forums but I can't seem to find a solution for this problem.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It would have been useful to post an example that allows copy&pasting. After I had to *type* your example, I can only tell, that I cannot reproduce the problem. I also had to assume you're working in the HTML scope and that you use `"draw_indent_guides": true` (which is default anyway)

Comment: I'm not sure why you felt the need to give a condescending reply. I didn't want to type it that badly you could have asked me to post the code instead of trying to make me feel stupid. Your last two assumptions are true.

Comment: You're right, that was unnecessary. I apologize.

Comment: I can actually reproduce your problem when selecting the “wrong” HTML syntax (e.g. “HTML (Rails)” or “HTML (Erlang)”). Using plain HTML works just fine in Sublime Text Build 3125 (several improvements have been made in 3103, in case you haven't updated)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly de same thing and found that I didn't have the font I had configured in font_face (consolas, in my case) so I changed the font to one I actually had (inconsolata, in my case) and the indentation guides worked perfectly (opensuse 42.2).